# How can i transform the utf8 chars to iso8859-1

Tags: ruby

the question is that the title say! who can tell me how do this in ruby!

Comment: On the whole I would say "Use UTF-8! Always!"; and do keep in mind that iso-8859-1 cannot represent the same set of characters that UTF-8 can. If you rely on this conversion, stuff is going to blow up of non-western characters sneak in at any point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### ~ UPDATE ~

`ruby-iconv` has been superseded from Ruby 1.9.3 onwards by the [encode](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-encode) method. See 
[Jörg W Mittag's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2737838/112538) for details, but in short:

```
utf8string = "èàòppè"
iso_string = utf8string.encode('ISO-8859-1')
```

---

I agree with Williham Totlandt in thinking that this type of conversion might not be the smartest idea ever, but anyway: use [ruby-iconv](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/iconv/rdoc/index.html) :)

```
utf8string = "èàòppè"
iso_string = Iconv.conv 'iso8859-1', 'UTF-8', utf8string
```

Comment: iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-encode

Answer (score 4):

With Ruby 1.9, that's particularly easy, because all strings carry their encoding with them:

```
# coding: UTF-8

u = 'µ'
```

As you can see, the string is encoded as UTF-8:

```
p u.encoding   # => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
p u.bytes.to_a # => [194, 181]
```

Transcoding the string is quite easy:

```
i = u.encode('ISO-8859-1')
```

`i` is now in ISO-8859-1 encoding:

```
p i.encoding   # => #<Encoding:ISO8859-1>
p i.bytes.to_a # => [181]
```

If you want to write to a file, the network, an IO stream or the console, it gets even easier. In Ruby 1.9, those objects are tagged with an encoding just like strings are, and transcoding happens automatically. Just say `print` or `puts` and Ruby will do the transcoding for you:

```
File.open('test.txt', 'w', encoding: 'ISO-8859-1') do |f|
  f.puts u
end
```