# Ruby equivalent to PHP's utf8_encode and utf8_decode functions

Tags: php, ruby, utf-8, utf8-decode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert a string from windows-1252 to utf-8 in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951891/how-can-i-convert-a-string-from-windows-1252-to-utf-8-in-ruby)
>   [How can i transform the utf8 chars to iso8859-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735734/how-can-i-transform-the-utf8-chars-to-iso8859-1)

So here's my problem. I have tools I've distributed across my internal LAN and my external web servers serve up jobs/data to the internal LAN.  As a result I'm often passing data I'd rather snoopy people didn't see. In other words, it's not the end of the world if someone sees my SQL string but I'd rather they didn't.  I know, it's like a deadbolt on a sliding glass door. It won't keep anyone truly determined out but it should discourage the random curious script kiddie.

So I have a set of simple ciphers I've written in PHP. Recently I've determined that my next extension to my toolset needs to be in Ruby but those new tools need to communicate with my previously built set of PHP tools - I don't want to rebuild all of the PHP tools. So I need my PHP ciphers to be exactly reproduced by my Ruby code so that when Ruby encrypts a string my PHP tools and decipher it, then pass back an encrypted string for my Ruby tools to decipher.

My simple ciphers are just modified Caesar ciphers. A Caesar cipher (for those unfamiliar with the name) is where you shift all characters by a single known number of letters - i.e. a shift of 3 turn A into D, B into E, C into F, etc. A true Caesar cipher would require wrapping so that a shift of 3 would turn a Z into a C.  However, mine doesn't do that, it simply adds 3 to Z and uses the utf8_encode and utf8_decode functions in PHP.

Now I need an equivalent in Ruby. I thought I'd found it in

```
str.encode('utf-8')
```

But that returns this error

> undefined method 'encode' for #

My Googling suggests there is no single solution to this in Ruby for some reason. Ruby needs to know the current encoding of the string before encoding it into UTF-8. At least that's the way I understood the issue.

So the string coming in would be whatever Ruby 1.8.7 defaults to. (In case this is useful... I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 desktop, US, English and I think I grabbed Ruby using apt-get with the default repositories.)  I need a variety of strings like SQL query statements - "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?" and strings produced by PHP's md5() output.  Every other string should fall into the category of upper case letters, lower case letters, and numbers all of it in US English.

Thanks

Comment: Forgive me if I'm overlooking something obvious, but should this not work? [How can I convert a string from windows-1252 to utf-8 in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951891/how-can-i-convert-a-string-from-windows-1252-to-utf-8-in-ruby)

Comment: `utf8_encode/decode` transform a string of bytes in ISO-8859-1 encoding to utf8 encoding and vice versa.

Comment: What does `utf8_encode` have to do with a Caesar cipher?

Comment: @deceze - I'd seen lots of comments about needing to know the current encoding before doing any other encoding. And then there are warnings about possibly having the chars encoded/decoded wrong. In my first iteration of the Caesar cipher I didn't wrap Z/z back around so when you add an integer to the ordinal value I get into the extended ASCII table. As a result I used utf8_encode/utf8_decode in PHP to handle this issue. It's only necessary because I didn't implement the wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Encoding](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Encoding.html) and look at the documentation for the [encode](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-encode) method you're using.I believe it is the first form that you need.

Comment: The pages you reference appear to be for Ruby 1.9.3 not 1.8.7. I was already trying the str.encode('utf8') bit - this appears to be valid only for Ruby 1.9+ not 1.8). Am I missing something in those links?

Comment: 1.8.7 doesn't know what character encoding is and doesn't care. This is why using 1.9 is essential if you have different character encodings used within your application. The 1.9.x series has been out for several years now and is actually better than 1.8.x has ever been. If you can, switch. If not, you'll have a *ton* of workarounds to implement.

Comment: Ruby 1.8.7 is standard with Ubuntu 12.04 and I have several machines that would need updating. I also use the encoding only for these ciphers (so far). So upgrading isn't likely at this time. I looked into using iconv but that didn't want to behave for me. However, `str.unpack('C*').pack('U*')` to get to UTF-8 and then `str.unpack('U*').pack('C*')` seems to be working. Now I'm fighting a subtle difference between the 2 languages. (When I have PHP decipher an encrypted string generated by Ruby PHP will often get every char right except the very first one.)